# Automatic box expander

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

#### Introduction

Sometimes, my boxes are too small to fit anything in it. I need you to make a box expander! So, what makes a box a box in this challenge.

```
 OOOO
O    O
O    O
O    O
 OOOO
```

The corners of the box are **always** spaces. The box itself can be made out of the same character. That character can be any [printable ASCII character](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5866/34718), except a space. So, that's these characters:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

The side lengths of the box above are **4, 3**. You may assume that the side length is always **positive**. That means that this is the smallest box you need to handle:

```
 #
# #
 #
```

In order to expand a box, you need to increment each side length. Let's go through this, step by step, with the above example. We first take the upper side of the box, which is:

```
 OOOO
```

We expand this by one, so we get:

```
 OOOOO
```

This is the upper and lower part of the box now. After that, we do the same with the sides on the left and right:

```
O
O
O
```

Becomes:

```
O
O
O
O
```

Now we reassemble the box, which results into:

```
 OOOOO
O     O
O     O
O     O
O     O
 OOOOO
```

#### The task

Given a box, expand it by 1. The box can be given in multiple lines, or in an array.

#### Test cases

```
 OOOO          OOOOO
O    O    >   O     O
 OOOO         O     O
               OOOOO

 XXXXXX        XXXXXXX
X      X  >   X       X
X      X      X       X
 XXXXXX       X       X
               XXXXXXX

 ~             ~~
~ ~       >   ~  ~
 ~            ~  ~
               ~~
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: can the box have a new line before it?

Comment: @Riley Yes, that is allowed :).

Comment: Can the box be padded with spaces?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, you may do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
yêpjÄ
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=ecOqcGrDhA&input=IE9PT08KTyAgICBPCk8gICAgTwpPICAgIE8KIE9PT08)

This is actually a byte longer than it should be. It should have been:

```
äêjÄ
```

But this has an unknown bug. :(

Explanation:

```
yê     "yank this colum
  p    "paste what we just yanked
   j   "move down to line 2
    Ä  "and duplicate this line
```

Comment: What does the other one do?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien `ä` is the duplicate operator (essentially "y" and "p" together in one byte) so `äê` is "duplicate column"

Answer (score 12):

## Vim, 7 bytes

```
♥GYPjYp
```

where ♥ is Control-V.

```
           The cursor starts on the first non-whitespace character of the first line.
♥G         Enter visual block mode and go to bottom of document.
  YP       Duplicate this column.
    j      Move down to the second line of the file.
     Yp    Duplicate this line.
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `YP` both times for consistency?

Comment: I accidentally hit `p` while recording the animation, so I stuck with it when transcribing the answer. Does it matter? >_>;

Comment: I just found the inconsistency odd, but I like your explanation.

Comment: This is exactly the same thing as my V answer, just that I happened to create one-byte mappings for `<C-v> G` and `YP`. It kinda makes my language feel cheap. :/

Comment: Hm, control-V shows up as a heart on my phone... ❤

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ That’s because it is one! ♥ It’s just a placeholder, of course.

Comment: @Lynn Ohh haha. ❤

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>57</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/^.(.)/gm,s="$&$1").replace(/(\n.*)/,s)
```

Explanation: The first regexp duplicates the second column and the second regexp duplicates the second row, thus enlarging the box as desired. Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to MartinEnder♦.

Answer (score 6):

### Python, <s>49</s> 42 bytes

Anonymous lambda:

-7 from **xnor**

```py
lambda s:[t[:2]+t[1:]for t in s[:2]+s[1:]]
```

Previous version:

```py
D=lambda s:s[:2]+s[1:]
lambda s:D(list(map(D,s)))
```

D is a function that duplicates the second item of a sequence.

Comment: The idea of re-using the function is clever, but it seems to be shorter to just repeat the code: `lambda L:[s[:2]+s[1:]for s in L[:2]+L[1:]]`.

Comment: Side note for the previous version: I think `map(D,D(s))` would give 43 instead

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/), 20 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
1`¶
¶$%'¶
%2=`.
$&$&
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=wrYKwrcKU2DCt8K3CiUoU2DCtwoxYMK2CsK2JCUnwrYKJTI9YC4KJCYkJgpTYCQ&input=IE9PT08KTyAgICBPCiBPT09PCgogWFhYWFhYClggICAgICBYClggICAgICBYCiBYWFhYWFgKCiB-Cn4gfgogfg) (There's several additional lines which enable a test suite where the test cases are separated by two linefeeds.)

#### Explanation

```
1`¶
¶$%'¶
```

`1` is a *limit* which restricts Retina to apply the substitution only to the first match it finds. `¶` matches a single linefeed, so we only need to consider replacing the linefeed at the end of the first line. It is replace with `¶$%'¶`, where `$%'` inserts the entire line following the match (a Retina-specific substitution element). Hence, this duplicates the second line.

```
%2=`.
$&$&
```

Here, `%` is per-line mode, so each line is processed individually, and the lines are joined again afterwards. `2=` is also a limit. This one means "apply the substitution only to the second match". The match itself is simple a single character and the substitution duplicates it. Hence, this stage duplicates the second column.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 24 bytes

```
f(a:b:c)=a:b:b:c
f.map f
```

Uses [RootTwo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89694/20260) idea of duplicating the second row and column. The `map f` does this to each row, and the `f.` then does this to the rows.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>57</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
param($n)($n-replace'^.(.)','$&$1')[0,1+1..$n.count]
```

Slightly similar to Neil's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89676/42963). The first replace matches the beginning of the line and the next two characters, and replaces them with the first character and second-character-twice. Instead of a second replace, it's swapped out for array-indexing to duplicate the second line. Takes input as an array of strings. The resultant array slices are left on the pipeline and printing is implicit.

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to Martin.*

Some examples:

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\automatic-box-expander.ps1 ' oooo ','o    o',' oooo '
 ooooo 
o     o
o     o
 ooooo 

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\automatic-box-expander.ps1 ' # ','# #',' # '
 ## 
#  #
#  #
 ##
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

**2 bytes thanks to Fatalize.**

```
{bB,?~c[A:C]hl2,A:Bc.}:1a.
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=e2JCLD9-Y1tBOkNdaGwyLEE6QmMufToxYS4&input=WyIgT09PTyI6Ik8gICAgTyI6Ik8gICAgTyI6Ik8gICAgTyI6IiBPT09PIl0&args=Wg)

Comment: [This is two bytes shorter](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=e2JCLD9-Y1tBOkNdaGwyLEE6QmMufToxYS4&input=WyIgT09PTyI6Ik8gICAgTyI6Ik8gICAgTyI6Ik8gICAgTyI6IiBPT09PIl0&args=Wg)

Comment: @Fatalize I never knew you can do it that way...

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
tZy"@:2hSY)!
```

Input is a 2D char array, with semicolon as row separator. For example, the first test case has input

```
[' OOOO ';'O    O';' OOOO ']
```

**Try it online!** Test cases [**1**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFp5IkA6MmhTWSkh&input=WycgT09PTyAnOydPICAgIE8nOycgT09PTyAnXQ), [**2**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFp5IkA6MmhTWSkh&input=WycgWFhYWFhYICc7J1ggICAgICBYJzsnWCAgICAgIFgnOycgWFhYWFhYICdd), [**3**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFp5IkA6MmhTWSkh&input=WycgfiAnOyd-IH4nOycgfiAnXQ).

#### Explanation

The code does the following twice: repeat the second row of the array and transpose.

To repeat the second row of an `m`×`n` array, the vector `[1 2 2 3 ... m]` is used as row index. This vector is generated as follows: range `[1 2 3 ... m]`, attach another `2`, sort.

```
t       % Take input implicitly. Duplicate
Zy      % Size of input as a two-element array [r, c]
"       % For each of r and c
  @     %   Push r in first iteration (or c in the second)
  :     %   Generate range [1 2 3 ... r] (or [1 2 3 ... c])
  2hS   %   Append another 2 and sort
  Y)    %   Apply as row index
  !     %   Transpose
        % End for. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
2{+(?x),1_x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLszKq1tawr9DUMYyvqNXn4krTUFLwBwIFJS4FBSV/BSDwBzOhopoAKk4Kog==)

`?x` removes duplicate rows of `x`, which in this case keeps all and only the first two rows. And `1_x` drops the first row. So append those together with `,` to extend along the vertical dimension.

Then follow up with a transpose `+` to exchange vertical and horizontal, and do it all again `2{ }/` to also extend the horizontal.

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
|:@(~.,}.)^:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpGdtY60XbxRroGBlwJVma/W/xspBo05Pp1ZPM87K6L8mV2pyRr5CmkIsSJVCcUlKZp66@n8Ff39/BS5/BQUFfy4IGwA)

Exact same strategy but you spell it a little differently:

- `~.` unique rows
- `}.` drop first row
- `,` append
- `|:@( )` then transpose
- `^:2` twice

Answer (score 2):

## SED <strike>69 19</strike> (14 + 1 for -r) 15

```
s/.(.)/&\1/;2p
```

Comment: Can't you just do `/.\(.\)/\0\1;2p`?

Comment: @Neil I looked all over for that `2p`, I figured there was a way to do it, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: The -r'' part is not needed as long as you add 1 byte for the r flag, thus saving 3 bytes. Also, since you edited your first version of the code, the explanation at the end is now not valid.

Comment: @Neil Couldn't believe my eyes when I saw the `\0` backreference, since they start at 1. The GNU sed's online manual speaks none of it. However, using `&` is I think equivalent and shorter.

Comment: @seshoumara Ah, those regexp version subtleties... which one uses `\0` then?

Comment: @Neil `\0` did worked in sed, I just never seen it mentioned. Of the top of my head, vim uses and documents `\0`, and also `&` which do the same. I'm sure many other regex flavors might have it, but no other one comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
L+<b2tbyMy
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%2B%3Cb2tbyMy&input=%22+OOOO%22%2C%22O++++O%22%2C%22O++++O%22%2C%22O++++O%22%2C%22+OOOO%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.10.0, <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
⊡->1.⇡+1△.
```

### [Explanation + See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__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)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 14 bytes

```
q~{~\_@]z}2*N*
```

Similar to [my MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89685/36398), but repeats the second-last row instead of the second.

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX57flxfQF16fTIqTio&input=WyIgWFhYWFhYICIgIlggICAgICBYIiAiWCAgICAgIFgiICJYICAgICAgWCIgIiBYWFhYWFggIl0)

#### Explanation

```
q                e# Read input
 ~               e# Interpret as an array
  {      }2*     e# Do this twice
   ~             e# Dump array contents onto the stack
    \            e# Swap top two elements
     _           e# Duplicate
      @          e# Rotate
       ]         e# Pack into an array again
        z        e# Zip
            N*   e# Join by newlines. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
{⍉⍵⌿⍨1+2=⍳≢⍵}⍣2
```

Test:

```
      smallbox largebox
┌───┬──────┐
│ # │ OOOO │
│# #│O    O│
│ # │O    O│
│   │O    O│
│   │ OOOO │
└───┴──────┘
      {⍉⍵⌿⍨1+2=⍳≢⍵}⍣2 ¨ smallbox largebox
┌────┬───────┐
│ ## │ OOOOO │
│#  #│O     O│
│#  #│O     O│
│ ## │O     O│
│    │O     O│
│    │ OOOOO │
└────┴───────┘
```

Explanation:

```
             ⍣2   run the following function 2 times:
{           }     stretch the box vertically and transpose
         ⍳≢⍵      indices of rows of box
       2=         bit-vector marking the 2nd row
  ⍵/⍨1+           replicate the 2nd row twice, all other rows once
 ⍉                transpose
```

Comment: The APL symbol monadic ⍉ is matrix transpose, which isn't the same thing as rotating by 90 degrees.

Comment: @JohnE: of course. I must've been more tired than I thought. Actually rotating by 90 degrees would be `⌽⍉` or `⊖⍉`, but in this case it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

## K, 15 bytes

```
2{+x@&1+1=!#x}/
```

Takes input as a matrix of characters:

```
  b: (" OOOO ";"O    O";" OOOO ")
(" OOOO "
 "O    O"
 " OOOO ")
```

Apply a function twice (`2{…}/`) which gives the transpose (`+`) of the right argument indexed (`x@`) by the incremental run-length decode (`&`) of one plus (`1+`) a list of the locations equal to 1 (`1=`) in the range from 0 up to (`!`) the size of the outer dimension of the right argument (`#x`).

Step by step,

```
  #b
3
  !#b
0 1 2
  1=!#b
0 1 0
  1+1=!#b
1 2 1
  &1+1=!#b
0 1 1 2
  b@&1+1=!#b
(" OOOO "
 "O    O"
 "O    O"
 " OOOO ")
  +b@&1+1=!#b
(" OO "
 "O  O"
 "O  O"
 "O  O"
 "O  O"
 " OO ")
  2{+x@&1+1=!#x}/b
(" OOOOO "
 "O     O"
 "O     O"
 " OOOOO ")
```

Try it [here](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%202%7B%2Bx%40%261%2B1%3D%21%23x%7D%2F%28%28%22%20%23%23%20%22%3B%22%23%20%20%23%22%29%400%201%200%29) with oK.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 11 bytes

```
⍥(⍉⊂◴:↘1.)2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2lKOKNieKKguKXtDrihpgxLikyCgpGIFsiIE9PT08gIgogICAiTyAgICBPIgogICAiIE9PT08gIl0KCkYgWyIgfiAiCiAgICJ-IH4iCiAgICIgfiAiXQo=)

Port of algorithmshark's [J and K answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272153/97916).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands/2649a799300cbf3770e2db37ce177d4a19035a25), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2FÀĆÁÁø
```

I/O as a list of strings.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fyO1ww5G2w41AuOP//2glBX8gUFDSUfJXAAJ/rAyomlgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V@m5JhcUpqYo5CZV1BaYqWgpFNpy6UUUJRaUlKpW1CUmVeSmoIkd2i3zn8jt8MNR9oONwLhjv@1MP35pSVQRZj6EXJA/Ye22f@PjlZS8AcCoIiSvwIQ@GNlQNXE6ihgU48iGwEGIPkIBTCIQGXCFUCU14FU1inUgWSA7NhYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
2F       # Loop 2 times:
  À      #  Rotate the rows in the list of strings once towards the left
         #  (which will use the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
   Ć     #  Enclose; append its own first item
    ÁÁ   #  Rotate the strings in the list twice towards the right
      ø  #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
         # (after the loop, the modified list of strings is output implicitly as result)
```

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, since `ø` works with lists of strings, whereas the new version of 05AB1E would require a matrix of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 39 bytes

```r
\(m,`?`=\(j)c(1:2,2:dim(m)[j]))m[?1,?2]
```

[The version with a formatted output](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZFNaoNAGIbpdk4xzOr76BdQG0oRxBN0l0VAhViroMmo6EgSSm_QG3RjCz1Ue5rOZEzA0C7m753neRcz7x_d-FkEX4MqFg_fEIOkTbgJYqgwA9f3yPOfSwkSoypBZDIKXQq9xPI_N29psCt7BUymqisPkIHggsStHv-vSHdIc6PLWxCOoCVa0JkibiPH-nNK19DTsWv2weq6jp_ItaB7vIjZKTi3mou1rvAscCUgLS_VDFmr30Ni0XRQ8bLmrl_rK53gCzPhdgqzZmdCnqUKZFTRNkHGzEHEtcDXab_Ke6WRPu_5QovtoPy4NgA7BI9pCy2leLbiekY3g_oDN3OhJbSfMo52_QU)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3NWI0cnUS7BNsYzSyNJM1DK2MdIysUjJzNXI1o7NiNTW5cqPtDXXsjWKh6t8m2uZkFpdocOUmlhRlVmgkaygpKOkoaQMxblpTx1hTB1VHUWqBhpKBko6JJkShAVRIASJkANGPqgpojE5SZVF-uW0IunEKYJURSjpmmnCNyWABmKkgiQigEUYQBWgaNHVM4EZzaXL5JhZopOkkakI8vWABhAYA)

The function takes a matrix of characters `m` as an input.

**Explanation:**

```
\                   # declare our function
  (m,               # a matrix passed as an argument
     `?`=\(j)       # internal function `?` is declared inside of the argument field
                    # instead of main function body to spare curly brackets 
c(1:2,2:dim(m)[j])) # the internal function body - outputs new matrix indices 
          m[?1,?2]  # main function outputs the modified matrix with two 2nd rows 
                    # and two 2nd columns
```

Answer (score 0):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 326 bytes

```
STRG a=READ[<here>+"\\a.txt"]
ROWS p=ROWSPLIT a BY ["\r\n"]
ROWS p=GETLINES p [1 TO p LENGTH-1]
ROWS p=p+p[1]+p[0]
STRG o=p[0]
ROWS y=EXTRACT COLLUM[2] FROM p SPLIT BY [""]
ROWS x=EXTRACT COLLUM[3] FROM p SPLIT BY [""]
[FOREACH NUMB IN 1 TO o LENGTH-1 AS i]
ROWS m=COMBINE[m,x] WITH [""]
ROWS m=COMBINE[y,m,y] WITH [""]
SHOW=m
```

I *definitely* need to add the nesting of functions, but this works very well

comment if you want an explanation

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>160</s> <s>146</s> 141 bytes

```
s=>{a=s[1];r="";l=s.split("\n");m=l.length;n=l[0].length;for(i=0;i<=m;i++){for(j=0;j<=n;j++)r+=!(i%m)&&j%n||i%m&&!(j%n)?a:" ";r+="\n"}return r}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
(1 2,1↓⍳)¨∘⍴⌷⊢
```

> > `(`
> >
> > > `1 2,` {1, 2} prepended to
> > >
> > > `1↓` one element dropped from
> > >
> > > `⍳` the indices
> >
> > `)¨` of each
>
> `∘` of
>
> > `⍴` the {row-count, column-count}
>
> `⌷` indexes into
>
> > `⊢` the argument

E.g. for

```apl
 XX
X  X
 XX
```

we find the indices; {1, 2, 3} for the rows, and {1, 2, 3, 4} for the columns. Now we drop the initial elements to get {2, 3} and {2, 3, 4}, and then prepend with {1, 2}, giving {1, 2, 2, 3} and {1, 2, 2, 3, 4}. Finally, we use this to select rows and columns, simultaneously doubling row 2 and column 2.

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%281%202%2C1%u2193%u2373%29%A8%u2218%u2374%u2337%u22A2%20%u22C4%20%28f%20f%20f%20m%29%28f%20f%20m%29%28f%20m%29%28m%u21903%203%u2374%27%20%23%20%23%27%29&run)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```
->a{a.map{|r|r.insert(2,r[1])}.insert(2,a[1])}
```

Very straighforward solution, taking input as array of lines. I don't like duplicated `insert`s, so will try to golf it.

Answer (score 0):

### C#, <s>127</s> 124 bytes

```
s=>{int n=s.Count-1,i=0;s[0]=s[n]=s[0].Insert(1,s[0][1]+"");s.Insert(1,s[1]);for(;i++<n;)s[i]=s[i].Insert(1," ");return s;};
```

Compiles to a `Func<List<string>, List<string>>`.

Formatted version:

```
s =>
{
    int n = s.Count - 1, i = 0;

    s[0] = s[n] = s[0].Insert(1, s[0][1] + "");

    s.Insert(1, s[1]);

    for (; i++ < n;)
        s[i] = s[i].Insert(1, " ");

    return s;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl -M5.10.0`, 23 bytes

```perl
s/.\K./$&$&/;$.==2&&say
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoicy8uXFxLLi8kJiQmLzskLj09MiYmc2F5IiwiYXJncyI6Ii1wbFxuLU01LjEwLjAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiBPT09PXG5PICAgIE9cbk8gICAgT1xuTyAgICBPXG4gT09PTyJ9)